# Running celery on windows

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, celeryd, djcelery

I'm working with Django and my development environment is Windows.
Yesterday I spent the WHOLE day trying to make celery run on my laptop with RabbitMQ.
I went through all the tutorials and nothing special was mentions about windows.
I followed this official documentation of Celery:
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Eventually I tried to run it on Ubuntu and everything worked.
The worker get stuck after running it with celery or manage.py celeryd:

**python manage.py celery worker -E -l debug**

```
[2014-06-18 07:23:48,516: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2014-06-18 07:23:48,525: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2014-06-18 07:23:48,532: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {StateDB, Timer, Hub, Queues (intra), Pool, Autoscaler, Beat, Autoreloader, Consumer}
[2014-06-18 07:23:48,549: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2014-06-18 07:23:48,553: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2014-06-18 07:23:48,569: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Mingle, Gossip, Tasks, Control, Agent, Heart, event loop}
[2014-06-18 07:23:48,582: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
```

I tried to run celeryd from cygwin but it didn't work too.
My RabbitMQ configuration is ok and I see that django is able to send messages to RabbitMQ.

I'm sure it's something related to windows and not defect configuration.
Here's my configuration:

```
# CELERY
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_HOST     = "127.0.0.1"
BROKER_PORT     = 5672
BROKER_USER     = "my_user"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "my_pass"
BROKER_VHOST    = "my_vhost"
```

I also used 'localhost' instead of 127.0.0.1.

Does any one knows something about celery on Windows? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "it got stuck"? I don't see any errors in your debug output.

Comment: It's not connecting to RabbitMQ and pulling messages.

Comment: The "Starting Pool" is the last line I'm getting from the worker and it's not functioning. Are you working with Celery on Windows?